# How to get almost one meter accuracy between mobile devices

Tags: react-native, gps, hybrid-mobile-app, geofencing

I am in search of a method to get one meter accuracy between mobile devices, with no luck so far. I was looking at gps and location based geo-fencing as an option, but i don't think I am going to get a one meter accuracy. The other option is with Bluetooth, but not sure about that as well.

Can I build a react-native app that can see whether two mobile devices with the app installed to get an accuracy as little as one meter using gps or any other device specific sensors?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your requirement. But to answer your questions, yes you should be able to get 1-meter displacement measurement between 2 geo-location.

Maybe you can check [how to achieve 1-meter accuracy in Android](https://www.gpsworld.com/how-to-achieve-1-meter-accuracy-in-android/)

There is other way, where you don't need 2 devices but you can find the distance of any object. That would require a phone with 2 cameras. If that fits the requirement of yours you can explore that area also.